# Homotopy between Homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, $\phi_0,\phi_1:X\rightarrow X$ be auto-homeomorphisms.  When can we construct a homotopy
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Phi &:X\times [0,1]\rightarrow X\\
&(x,t)\mapsto \Phi(x,t)
\end{aligned}
$$
such that $\Phi(x,i)=\phi_i(x)$, for $i=0,1$ and for each $t \in [0,1]$, $x\mapsto \Phi(x,t)$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: Sorry, it should say "when can we construct...$\Phi$"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is asking about the path components of the space $\operatorname{Homeo}(\mathbb{R}^n , \mathbb{R}^n)$.

Let's do a warm up question which is to compute the path components of $\operatorname{Diffeo}(\mathbb{R}^n , \mathbb{R}^n)$. By translation, the inclusion of the diffeomorphisms fixing the origin is a deformation retraction, so we may assume that our diffeomorphisms fix the origin.

Locally near the origin, the map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ behaves like its matrix of partial derivatives. By essentially zooming in infinitely far, we give a path from $f$ to $f'$ that depends continuously on $f$. Hence, we have a deformation retraction of $\operatorname{Diffeo}(\mathbb{R}^n , \mathbb{R}^n)$ to $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, and the latter has two path components which are determined by the degree of the map. See [http://people.math.harvard.edu/~kupers/teaching/272x/book.pdf](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Ekupers/teaching/272x/book.pdf) Theorem 9.1.1 for a precise argument.

Much more difficult is the topological case, but from above you might conjecture there are exactly two path components depending on the degree of the map. It relies on a difficult theorem that all degree 1 homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are stable, meaning they are a composition of homeomorphisms that are the identity on an open subset.

It is easy to prove that a stable homeomorphism is isotopic to the identity, so there are two path components of $\operatorname{Homeo}(\mathbb{R}^n , \mathbb{R}^n)$. For references, I point you to chapter 26 of the above notes by Kupers.

So to directly answer your question, you have such a homotopy, if and only if, both are orientation preserving or both reversing.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer (so visually insightful... I really liked the argument reducing things to the familiar $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ topological group).  So may I ask, if both $\phi_i$ are orientation preserving (resp. both orientation reversing) then how can we explicitly construct such a homotopy?  That is, once we have reduced the problem to these two cases, as you have shown (with great references may I add).

Comment: @AnnieLeKatsu If they are not differentiable, I imagine it is very difficult. It depends on whether or not the proof of the stable homeomorphism theorem is constructive. I imagine it is not, but I have not seen a proof.

Comment: Ah, okay, so it is very much non-trivial.  Interesting then!  Thank you Connor

Comment: @AnnieLeKatsu Of course! I is an interesting question. If you are interested in manifolds, specifically these questions about isotopy, I would highly recommend those notes. The field is still pretty active, and there might even be a little bit of a resurgence if my adviser is correct.

Comment: Yes, I have come across these notes a few months back but hadn't had the time to look deeper.  I think I'll take a second look.  Thanks Connor :)

Comment: @AnnieLeKatsu Sorry do not mean to comment so much, but if you know that your two homeomorphisms are differentiable at a single point (which can be different for each one), you do have an explicit path. First you translate so that the differentiable point is fixed, then you zoom in to the derivative at this point. Then you will have two linear functions, and choose your favorite explicit path between these two matrices.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  This is what I actually was doing, "infinitesimally interpolating on the Lie algebra" but I was curious is there was another way to go about it.  Thanks btw.