# Connectedness of the set of continuous bijections $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, product-space

> Consider $X = \{ f :\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n \mid f \text{ continuous bijection } \} $ endowed with the product topology inherited possibly from $\Bbb R^{{n}^{\Bbb R^n}}$ (terrible notation). Is $X$ connected or disconnected?

When $n = 1$ I think I've managed to figure out that $X$ can be partitioned to $A = \{f \in X \mid f \text{ increasing }\}$ and $B = \{f \in X \mid f \text{ decreasing } \}$  and so $$X = A \cup B$$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ making $X$ disconnected.

The problem with $n > 1$ is that we only have this sort of characterization of bijective functions to increasing and decreasing sets in $\Bbb R$ as there is some kind of order defined in it. We lose this when we go up dimensions. Is there some "invariant" or another clever way to classify bijections in larger dimensions of $\Bbb R$ that we could use to find a separation for $X$? Or is it even true that $X$ is disconnected when $n > 1$?

Comment: Any line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ will also have a monotone image for the same reason you've already given. Pick one and use the same argument.

Comment: @CyclotomicField That doesn't show that two "opposite" maps are in different connected components, because one can go through maps that don't share the same image. Consider $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=-x$ in $\Bbb R^n$ with $n\ge2$, for example—those are in the same connected component via rotations.

Comment: @GregMartin yeah good point, rotations screw this up.

Comment: You can divide $X$ into orientation-preserving and orientation-reversing maps. Showing that it has exactly two components is more difficult. Try [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799977/homotopy-between-homeomorphisms).

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ both closed or both open? You might want to add this information I think?

Comment: @BrunoB I don't think it makes much difference, but in the case with $\Bbb R$ the sets are closed both.

Comment: Oh sorry if it wasn't clear but I just wanted to be sure that you weren't just saying "$X = A \cup B$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$ so $X$ is disconnected" without other assumptions, since that would be trivially wrong in general. So I wasn't really asking if it was specifically "both open" or "both closed", just that it was at least one of the two, sorry again.